# turf function booleanPointOnLine returns wrong result

Tags: leaflet, turfjs

If I try to use `booleanPointOnLine`, it always returns false. Even if point is placed on line.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4gnmtjh/1/)

You can see two lines where one marker is placed on line and another is not:

[image]

`booleanPointOnLine` returns false for both.

If I try to change epsilon parameter to whatever number, `booleanPointOnLine` returns true for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you set the epsilon to a to high value. You need a lower one because it depends on the length of the decimal places:

```
{ epsilon: 5e-8 }
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/bxueharL/